# Complement and supplement angles

Tags: geometry

This High school Honors geometry question got my eyes turn around my head, in part of the language involved.
It goes like: "The supplement of an angle is 60 degrees less than twice the supplement of the complement of the angle". Find the measure of the complement.
Any ideas? Thanx

Comment: @G-man .Yes, 10th grade Honors Geometry private College Prep High School, and I couldn't do this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $180-x=(...)-60$. Try to sort out what goes in the missing spot.

Comment: If the angle is $x$, the complement is $90-x$ and the supplement of the complement is $90+x$ and so twice means $180+2x$. So that is what goes on the dots?

Comment: Thankx, I will work it out!